# How to generate code before compiling in C?

Tags: c, gcc

Let assume I have a loop like this:

```
#define UF 1 // Unroll Factor
for(i=0; i<N-UF+1; i+=UF)
  a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
```

I want to unroll the loop with `UF = 4`. For this purpose, I should change the code like this:

```
for(i=0; i<N-UF+1; i+=UF){
  a[i+0] = b[i+0] + c[i+0];
  a[i+1] = b[i+1] + c[i+1];
  a[i+2] = b[i+2] + c[i+2];
  a[i+3] = b[i+3] + c[i+3];
}
```

Well, I want it to apply another `UF`, and I have to change the code!
If I could do some thing like this my problem is solved:

```
 for(i=0; i<N-UF+1; i+=UF){
   //The following loop should generate code somthing like it prints the body 
   /for(j=0; j<UF;j++){
      a[i+j] = b[i+j] + c[i+j];
   }/
}
```

I can use `fprintf` and generate another file but it takes too much time I want a faster way. Is there any way to implement it in a single function and use it before compiling? I want to see the compiler's behavior So I need to change them in my code. If there are any solution I appreciate it.
I use `C` so `C++` and Templates are not useful for this question.
Using `GCC 6.2.0`-`Linux`

Comment: To first order, either you should be letting the compiler do this for you, or you should be writing assembly language by hand.  The GNU assembler has a macro language that is actually _more powerful_ than the C preprocessor; in particular, IIRC it _can_ iterate, which CPP can't.

Comment: I use `O3` so the compiler will do it but I want to tell the compiler and use my unroll factor

Comment: I believe GCC has some `-f` options to the purpose, which you may be able to apply to a single function using pragmas.

Comment: @zwol, actually I could not find. You mean it is possible to use `#pragma -funroll-loops` before the loop? GCC has the following `-f` option for unrolling:
 `-fsplit-ivs-in-unroller       [enabled]`
 `-funroll-all-loops            [disabled]`
 `-funroll-loops                [disabled]`
 `-fvariable-expansion-in-unroller  [disabled]`
I find them with this command: `gcc -c -Q -O3 --help=optimizers | grep unrol
`

Comment: So you mean I have to implement an assembly macro and use it in my code?

Comment: The point is, why do you insist on unrolling by hand in the first place? Why not just let the compiler decide? It most likely knows much better that you (or me) about cache-lines, internal bus-widths, register utilisation, etc. Did you profile your code against the compiler generated? Are you sure **this** is your bottleneck? Did you layout/align your datastructure properly? With modern superscalar multi-issue CPUs even a simple loop with proper data layout could be much faster than a hand-optimised partially unrolled loop with inappropriate datastructures.

Comment: If you have some idea of the maximum that UF will be, you can use [Duff's device](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, Thanks, Duff's device could help. I should test.

Comment: @Olaf. The point is compilers are smarter than me to unroll when just unrolling is the goal. But, I'm looking for other optimization which compiler is not smart enough. this method will help me to help the optimizer. Yes every this is OK with my code such as alignment, etc.

Comment: @FackedDeveloper Until now, you did not give any evidence of your claim.  Just reading the machine code is often not sufficient. For instance: nserting `nop`s at the right place can make your code faster! As I said, you should profile. And try different compilers. gcc for isntance is know to make great leaps even from one minor version to the next.

Comment: @Olaf, Because I am not sure about my claim, I need to prove it by hand written codes and need a faster method to test my ideas. But, Compilers are not smart enough! I am sure about it. For profiling, yes I ordinally use perf. For compiling, I use Clang and GCC and hope to be able to install ICC on my Linux. I can not understand it's installation process! I hate to install these kinds of stuff on my Linux.